# accessing document.getElementById from another window

Tags: javascript, html

I have two .html files (Intro.html and Main.html) sharing an external .js file.

My first .html file opens up the 2nd .html via a customized button and .online event from the external .js file using

```
document.getElementById("leaveButton").onclick = function () {
    location = "Main.html";
}
```

My second .html file also has several buttons on its own page/window also being accessed by document.getElementById.onclick from the external .js file.

There are no problems and everything works fine if I keep separate .js files for each .html file.

However, when I have them share the same .js file, each .html page in the console complains about the other's document.getElementById("idName").onclick items.  This is the error message I get,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

How do I resolve this using pure Javascript?

Comment: Use different scripts for different pages. If the scripts needs an element with a certain ID and the page does not have such an element, probably the script should not be included in that page, right?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to only attempt to add the `onclick()` handler if the element exists. Something like:

```
if (!!document.getElementById("leaveButton")) {
  document.getElementById("leaveButton").onclick = function () {
    location = "Main.html";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Carl.  Can you tell me details about the other solutions as well?